# What does a problem not in $NSPACE(cn / \log(n))$ tell me?

Tags: complexity-theory, decision-problem

I have the following two resuts taken from the book "The Classical Decision Problem".

[image]

[image]

How does Corollary 6.3.28 follow? How can I derive PSPACE-hardness from non-membership in $NSPACE(cn / \log(n))$?

Comment: Is $c$ constant? Are you asking about NEXPTIME?

Comment: @BaderAbuRadi no, I'm asking about the class in the title. It is a subset of NEXPTIME